# parse html within ng-repeat

Tags: html, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been searching for hours now and I can't seem to find how to parse HTML code when retrieving using ng-repeat. I checked out $sce.trustAsHtml but I don't know how to apply it in my code.

html file:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>My Links</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>URL</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="stuff in myStuff()">
                <td>{{stuff.name}}</td>
                <td>{{stuff.url}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.myStuff = function() {
    return [
        {
            'name':'Google',
            'url':'<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>'
        },
        {
            'name':'Yahoo',
            'url':'<a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>'
        },
        {
            'name':'Microsoft',
            'url':'<a href="http://microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>'
        }
    ];
};
});
```

It's displaying the HTML source but I want it compile the code. Is my JS approach wrong? I'll be applying it to a json file using $http directive once I figure this out. Can anyone shed some light? I have my code at http://jsfiddle.net/s2ykvy8n/

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include [`ng-sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) script and in your module add dependency.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

and just use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
     <td ng-bind-html="stuff.url"></td>
```

and you are good to go:-

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYiCkf?p=preview)**

With what you are doing, the html in the binding will be displayed as textcontent in the element while processed by interpolation directive.

Comment: Forgot about this! Good stuff.

Comment: @PSL that's it! i tried ngSanitize before but didn't work. now i know why. i assumed that angular.min.js is complete. turns out it didn't have angular-sanitize.js. now that i also include that, it works. thank you

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination (since from your example, you are just returning links) is to advise you to remove the html from your returned json and just return the url as a string.

Format:

```
{
    'name': 'Google',
    'url': 'http://google.com'
}
```

Then your HTML looks like this,

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="stuff in myStuff()">
        <td>{{stuff.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{stuff.url}}">{{stuff.name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But, if you **MUST** have HTML strings in your json file, I would take a look at [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). There are examples towards the bottom that can help you on how you can create a directive to compile your 'url' string to HTML

Comment: i used link as a simple example to get an idea of how to do it. the data i'll be handling has more html tags like text styles. i will take a look at $compile. thanks for the suggestion.